# Move player at godot4

Tags: animation, godot, godot-4

I designed a character that has 4 walking modes for godot4.
I saved the picture in PNG format.

I enter it into the animation section. When I set the keyframes and play, in addition to playing the animation, the position of the character in the X direction is also changed.
I checked that the position of the character does not change in the settings, but the character moves in the X direction when playing.
How can I keep the position of the character fixed so that it does not move in an animation?

Comment: Can you show us an example in screenshots or an animated gif, just to be sure we're correctly understanding your setup and the symptoms of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have sprites that are of different sizes for the animation? That might be the cause of the problem. If so, making them the same size would solve the problem.

Alternatively, you could change the `offset` of your sprite to compensate for the apparent movement.